# Why am I getting this error when uploading app to device?

Tags: ios, xcode

I changed the name of my app, and get this error when trying to put it on iphone. It was working fine before changing the name.

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6wk6rkwk4n0jcw/Screenshot%202015-06-19%2023.43.00.png?dl=0

Comment: The build output will show a lot more detail about the error. There is no way to help with what little you've shown so far.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m6wk6rkwk4n0jcw/Screenshot%202015-06-19%2023.43.00.png?dl=0

Comment: The error went away but now after I deploy the app, nothing shows up when I click on it.

Comment: Have you changed the name of your project in "Manage Schemes" as well?

Comment: http://puu.sh/ivGef/707f97853e.png I'm still getting a black screen

Answer (score 0):

Try a clean build doing this: `cmd`+`shift`+`k` and then `cmd`+`b`. This should solve the problem.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I got rid of the error, but when I click on the app, it's just a black screen. It created another app, called syncornice. The original app was called stoptime, but I changed the title to syncronice http://puu.sh/ivFYB/28e2aef93f.png

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5o4ay1psmia0c5c/Screenshot%202015-06-20%2000.14.23.png?dl=0

Comment: Delete both apps from your iPhone. Then do the clean build and run again.

Answer (score 0):

In your project select "Supporting Files" and locate the info.plist

Change the "Bundle display name" key value to the new name.

[image]
[image]

Delete the app from the simulator or any other physical device.

Clean and Build your app.

It should work now.